# Lost my Site UUID in drupal 8 and can't find it

Tags: configuration, drupal-8

I Accidently removed my sites/defaul/files/conf_* folder. I want to recreate it but can't seem to find my UUID hash anywhere. Does anyone have an idea where to find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `sites/default/settings.php` file, you'll see strings like `$config_directories['active']` and `$config_directories['staging']`. There, you'll be able to see your config folder hashes.